# Email: A Job for the Client or the API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, client, lumen

I want my new project to have an API and a client working together, but I want the application to have a lot of features, one of which is sending email. I had my mind set on using [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) (the micro-framework), but am now wondering if I should switch to a full-stack framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), as Lumen doesn't include email functionality out-of-the-box.

Is emailing a job for the API? If so, where should it happen, just before sending a response?

My last question is quite broad but: Do I need a framework to build a REST API and can I just create it using pure PHP?

I don't expect any code from anyone, but some hints or a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: No. Whenever you want to send it. Yes it can be done in just PHP, frameworks can't do anything that cannot be done naively. PHP has a [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) method that sends an email, you don't need anything extra for it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a framework to send an e-mail to your clients. PHP has a built-in mail function, you can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Because PHP is a single-threaded process, the email will be sent before the server returns a response to the client, unless you flush the buffers response before you send the mail.

You do not need a framework to build a REST API. You can do this yourself, however you will to reinvent the wheel, as many API's have great REST capabilities.